# Supremum Proof:

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Show sup{−1/n: n∈N}=0.
So far I have the following:  Let b be an upper bound.  Suppose b<0.  b<-1/n which is equivalent to -b>1/n. I don't know what to do from here and if I'm approaching the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** If we define a sequence $(a_n)_n = -\frac{1}{n}$, then we know that $0$ is an upper bound (since all the elements of this sequence are negative numbers). Then suppose for a contradiction that there exists a smaller upper bound than $0$, say $b$; and we know that $b < 0$. Then, we can use Archimedian Property to show that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $a_n = -\frac{1}{n} > b$ for some $n$, which is contradictory to the assumption $b$ is an upper bound.

Answer (score -1):

You can use that $\sup(-A) = - \inf(A)$, i.e, your problem now is to compute $\inf\left \{ \frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right \}$, can you proceed from here or do you want more help ?

Comment: In the class I am doing this for we have not learned inf so that really doesn't help.  We need to show 0 is an upper bound and the least upper bound

Comment: If $b<0$ is an upper bound, then $0 > b > -\frac{1}{n}, \forall n$ and $0 < -b<\frac{1}{n}$, but given a positive real number, for instance -b, it is possible to take $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < -b$. What next ?

Comment: Is that a contradiction since a negative number cannot be greater than a positive number.

Comment: Note that if $0<-b<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $n < -\frac{1}{b}=K$. This would mean the natural numbers have an upper bound.